# Unrecognized option --kill-at when linking library on linux

Tags: c++, linux

When I run ld --help, it still show that ld have --kill-at option.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to i386 PE port of the linker, in other words for windows. As such the option would be usable in a cross-compiler linker, but would not be implemented for a non windows linker. Compiling for ubuntu you don't need this.

Comment: So in linux, exported stdcall functions are not renamed when linking?

Comment: Without me knowing what you're trying to do, at least that option is windows specific and will not work with compilers not targeting the windows platform.

Comment: I want to export a function with stdcall calling convention without @x prefix after function's name. Thanks for your answer anw :D